# ASP.NET MVC Core update record stored procedure returning nothing

Tags: stored-procedures, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having a problem with ASP.NET MVC Core in that there seems to be some caching or SQL hasn't completely finished executing.

I am running a stored procedure to update an already existing record (which is successful, the `isPublished` flag changes from 0 to 1) but on the following page load, Entity Framework is unable to find that record even though `isPublished` has been set to 1.

Having said that, once I restart the debug session in Visual Studio, it works as expected.

I have a feeling, perhaps that the SQL doesn't quite execute completely, or that it caches?

Does anyone have an idea what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

It turns out that my service, in startup.cs, was AddSingleton.

```
services.AddSingleton<IPersonService, PersonService>(); //Needs to be AddScoped
services.AddSingleton<IPersonRepository, PersonRepository>(); //Also needs to be AddScoped
```

This wouldn't have worked as singleton will only be created once and will be the same instance for **every** http request.

What we need is a new instance for every http request.

Also, make sure that the services' scope is the same as the repositories.

For more information you can go to this page 
[What is the difference between services.AddTransient, service.AddScope and service.AddSingleton methods in Asp.Net Core 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/what-is-the-difference-between-services-addtransient-service-addscope-and-servi)

Please make any amendments to this if it's not all correct!

Hope this helps =)