# What are the practical scenarios to use IServiceCollection.AddTransient, IServiceCollection.AddSingleton and IServiceCollectionAddScoped Methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/what-is-the-difference-between-services-addtransient-service-addscope-and-servi) post I can understand the differences between `AddTransient`,`AddScoped` and `AddSingleton` however, I am unable to see the practical usage of each of them.

My understanding is

**AddTransient**

Creates a new instance every time when the client asks for it.

```
services.AddTransient<IDataAccess, DataAccess>();
```

will return a new DataAccess object every time a client code asks for it. More likely a constructor.

**Usage of AddTransient**

In cases when we have to access a database to read and update it and destroy the access object (DataAccess) its best to use `AddTransient` - Not sure about the thread safty.

**AddScoped**

Creates a new instance for each http web request.

**Usage of AddScoped**

```
 services.AddScoped<ShoppingCart>(serviceProvider => ShoppingCart.GetShoppingCart(serviceProvider));
```

this mean each web request will be having its own shopping cart instance which intern means each user / client will be having its own shoping cart instance for that http web request.

**AddSingleton**

Create single instance for all the http web requests.

**Usage of AddSingleton**

Found this code in an sample application but I dont understand how it is being useful.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Can someone please give a decent practical example when to use AddSingleton and check if my understanding of AddTransient and AddScoped is correct?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your understanding of all 3 scopes is correct.

**Transient** would be used when the component cannot be shared. A non-thread-safe database access object would be one example.

**Scoped** can be used for Entity Framework database contexts. The main reason is that then entities gotten from the database will be attached to the *same context* that all components in the request see. Of course if you plan on doing queries with it in parallel, you can't use Scoped.

Another example of a Scoped object would be some kind of a `RequestContext` class, that contains e.g. the username of the caller. A middleware/MVC filter can request it and fill out the info, and other components down the line can also request for it, and it will surely contain the info for the current request.

**Singleton** components are shared always, so they are best for thread-safe components that do not need to be bound to a request. An example would be `IOptions`, which gives access to configuration settings. An `HttpClient` wrapper class that uses `SendAsync` on a single static `HttpClient` instance would also be completely thread-safe, and a good candidate for being a Singleton.

Note that if you have a Singleton component that depends on a Scoped component, its dependency would get disposed before it. Thus a component cannot depend on another component that has smaller scope than itself.

Comment: Thank yo Juunas, a good explaination however, i was expecting an answer with some concrete examples - may be its too early to ask for that.

Comment: If I read this right, then Singleton is to prefer over Scoped and Transient (because re-creating objects unnecessarily often seems unnecessary), but for the cases we can't use it (e.g. because of non-thread-safe code), we have to use one of the other two (depending on our needs).

Comment: That's the way I think at least :)

Comment: @PeppeL-G Would it be correct if the DbContext object is set as Transient? DbConext class is from Entity Framework and is used to access the database objects like tables views etc...

Comment: @YawarMurtaza I would say yes, assuming the services using it are marked as transient as well. EF contexts can be transient or scoped, not really singleton. The reason Scoped is often used is so that multiple services in the request can do modifications and queries against the same instance of the context and finally SaveChanges() saves all of them at once. Transient means you can't do that but offers higher isolation of course :)

Comment: When I see the source code of `services.AddDbContext()`, I found that it use `ServiceLifetime.Scoped` by default. So can you explain more your statement: "Of course if you plan on doing queries with it in parallel, you can't use Scoped."? can give an example of that 'parallel'?

Comment: That might be a bit unclear. The point is that an EF DbContext cannot run multiple queries from multiple threads at once, and thus is not thread-safe. So any lifetime in the DI container could hit this problem, not just Scoped. When the lifetime is Scoped, it means you could be injecting two services into a controller, that both run a query on an EF context. Now if you decided to run these service calls in parallel, you would hit problems since both services use the same EF context instance. By using Transient, both services would get their own instances and could be run in parallel.

Comment: I want to ask - Assuming there is a SendMail method in SMTPClient class and this method is not thread safe. So if I have this method (SMTPClient.SendMail) inside an singleton class, then I believe it is OK as long as I force create a new instance of the SMTPClient, correct?

Comment: Yeah if you create a new instance within the singleton's method, so it is specific to that invocation.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen the "just use `AddTransient<T>()`" view, but I don't agree.

### Think about memory allocation

I hate allocating things when I don't have to, so if I know I'm creating something that's thread-safe, or that I have explicit documentation that having a singleton instance is the expected usage, then I'm creating a singleton.

### AddSingleton()

Here's the ApplicationInsights TelemetryClient instance as a singleton. Their documentation says this works.

```
telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
services.AddSingleton<TelemetryClient>(telemetryClient);
```

In this project I use Azure Table Storage as well, and I've found that creating a CloudTableClient as a singleton works just fine. I don't need to keep creating instances of it for every request.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Configuration.GetValue<string>("storageAccountConnectionString"));
CloudTableClient someTableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
services.AddSingleton<CloudTableClient>(someTableClient);
```

In some sense, it's the equivalent of a class's readonly static property, for instance:

```
public static readonly CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = new CloudTableClient(...);
```

... there's only one instance of it in the whole application, but by using `services.AddSingleton<T>()` we get direct access to it using Dependency Injection.

### AddScoped()

An example of `AddScoped<T>()` for me is that I want to embed the JavaScript that I need to get Application Insights into a web page, but I use [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src), so I need to put a nonce on any on-page JavaScript. I have a little bit of code that helps me do it.

```
services.AddScoped<ApplicationInsightsJsHelper>();
```

### AddTransient()

I haven't found a need to use `AddTransient<T>()` for anything yet. It could be that I don't think of things that I have to create, every time I need them, as "services"... they're just variables that I new up. In some sense, `AddTransient<T>()` is a hidden use of the Factory pattern... instead of calling a static `MyServiceFactory.Create()` function, you have Dependency Injection (effectively) do the same thing for you.

Comment: As the post says, it all up to the need of project requirements