# AddScope vs AddScoped

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection

The current docs on ASP.NET dependency injection describe an [`AddScoped`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddScoped_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Type_) method, which I also see as a member of `IServiceCollection` in Visual Studio's autocompletion when working on an ASP.NET project.

However, there are also many references on the internet (including on the MSDN blog) to an `AddScope` method which doesn't seem to be referenced in the official docs and doesn't show up for me in Visual Studio. Examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38138100/1709587), [2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/01/26/comparing-asp-net-core-ioc-service-life-times-and-autofac-ioc-instance-scopes/), [3](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/741). In fact, a Google search for `asp.net "addscope"` turns up roughly the same number of results as `asp.net "addscoped"`; these two names are used roughly equally often.

It would seem incredible if all of these references were just typos - surely this method name doesn't get typoed almost 50% of time consistently across the entire internet? But that makes it all the more confusing that I can't find any reference to `AddScope` in any official documentation. Was this a method that used to exist, or an old alias for `AddScoped`, or is something else going on here? What exactly is or was `AddScope`?

Comment: It looks like typos to me, many articles use both and quite a lot have nothing to do with IServiceCollection.

Comment: Example from page 2: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33483/Windows-Indexing-Service-Basics