# Onion architecture : respecting dependencies in the MVC Layer of the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, onion-architecture

I am making a website using ASP.NET MVC and an onion architecture. I have the following architecture:

1. Domain : Entities / Domain Interfaces
2. Repository : Generic repository (for now) using Entity Framework Code First Approach
3. Service : Generic Service that calls the Repository
4. MVC

Now I am trying to create a method in my controller to start testing the methods I have implemented in `Repository` and `Service`, and I am having a hard time as to what I am allowed to create in this controller. I want to test a simple `Get` method in the `Repository`, but to do that I need `GenericService` object and `GenericRepository` object in my controller. To demonstrate what I mean here's a snippet of my GenericRepository(I will skip the interfaces):

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly PrincipalServerContext context;
    private DbSet<T> entities;
    public Repository(PrincipalServerContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        entities = context.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Now my GenericService:

```
public class GenericService<T> : IGenericService<T> where T : class
{
    private IRepository<T> repository;

    public GenericService(IRepository<T> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    public T GetEntity(long id)
    {
        return repository.Get(id);
    }
}
```

And finally, my question, am I allowed to create these objects in my controller as follows (using my dbcontext called PrincipalServerContext):

```
public class NavigationController : Controller
{
    private IGenericService<DomainModelClassHere> domainService;
    private IGenericRepository<DomainModelClassHere> domainRepo;
    private PrincipalServerContext context;

    public ActionResult MyMethod(){
        context = new PrincipalServerContext();
        domainRepo = new GenericRepository<DomainModelClassHere>(context);
        domainService = new GenericService<DomainModelClassHere>(domainRepo);
        if(domainService.GetEntity(1)==null)
           return View("UserNotFound");//Just as an example
        return View();
    }
}
```

Is this allowed? According to Jeffrey Palermo, UI can depend on `Service` and `Domain` so I don't know about the `Repository`. Technically I am not using methods from `repository`, but I do need to add a reference to the project.

If I can't then how can I create a new `GenericService` if I don't have a `GenericRepository`? Is there a better way to instantiate my objects ?

**EDIT** I think the answer to my question resides in `Startup.cs` where I can put something like `service.addScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>),typeof(GenericRepository<>));`
but I 'm not sure about this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this on my own if ever someone encounters the same problem. There are configuration methods we can use to create instances of classes when needed. In the `Startup.cs` file you have to add `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method and inside there are several methods that can be applied to `services` to create these instances. For example you can use:

```
services.AddTransient(IGenericRepository, GenericRepository)
```

[What is the difference between services.AddTransient, service.AddScope and service.AddSingleton methods in Asp.Net Core 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/what-is-the-difference-between-services-addtransient-service-addscope-and-servi) (this link explains differences between methods).

`AddTransient` is good in my case because it creates an instance of an object through the whole lifespan of the application, which is what I need. This means UI is dependant on the rest of the solution, because Startup.cs needs to know about the `Repositories` as well as the `Services`.
 A pretty good answer can be found here :[Onion Architecture : Can UI depend on Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656592/onion-architecture-can-ui-depend-on-domain/44657017#44657017).

Comment: re: `AddTransient is good in my case because it creates an instance of an object through the whole lifespan of the application, which is what I need.` Actually, what you need is `AddSingleton`, if you want a single instance across the lifetime of the app, which all controllers+requests would share. *That said, in your case, I do not think you want this* (each request sharing a Repo/DBContext). So you should register the `PrincipleServerContext` with `IServiceCollection.AddDBContext` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro#register-the-context-with-dependency-injection