# Instantiating a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Below is my sample code. I have this class whose constructor takes an `IConfigurationRoot` parameter and uses it to set a private field:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

    public class MyClass(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        // I believe this has been injected
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

Now I want to instantiate that class:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _configuration;
    private MyClass myclass;

    public SomeMethod()
    {
         // My _configuration here gets null in the debugger
         MyClass myclass = new MyClass(_configuration);

         // Rest of method omitted...
    }
}
```

How do I properly instantiated that class so that it doesn't end up being null?

Comment: I think you need to use `ConfigurationBuilder`. See if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) might help.

Comment: Your dependencies should be injected.

Comment: `IConfigurationRoot _configuration;` You should build configuration . Something like `_configuration = ConfigurationBuilder.Build()`

Comment: Thank you @Sach, @Eldho! ConfigurationBuilder answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this process:

1.) What I have done is map a section of the AppSettings.json file to an object.

A.) Add the configuration settings to `json` file.

```
"MyConfiguration": {

  "DBServer": "MyDBServer",
  "DBName": "MyDatabase"
}
```

B.) Create a class to use strongly typed configurations.

```
public class MyConfiguration
{
     public string DBServer { get; set;}
     public string DBName { get; set;}
}
```

C.) Map the JSON configurations to the `MyConfiguration` object in the `Startup` class.

```
public class Startup
{

   //Make sure you add this.
   public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       ...

       var configSection = Configuration.GetSection("MyConfiguration");

       services.Configure<MyConfiguration>(configSection);

       //Use one of the following.            
       Services.AddScoped<MyClass>();
       Services.AddTransient<MyClass>();
       Services.AddSingleton<MyClass>();
       Services.AddInstance<MyClass>();
       ...
   }
}
```

See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/what-is-the-difference-between-services-addtransient-service-addscope-and-servi) for an explanation of the differences between

```
`AddSingleton()`
`AddScopped()`
`AddInstance()`
`AddTransient()`
```

2.) Change `MyClass` to have `MyConfiguration` object as a parameter of the `MyClass` constructor.

```
//add this using statement and corresponding package
//"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.1"
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public class MyClass
{
    private MyConfiguration _configuration;


    public MyClass(IOptions<MyConfiguration> configuration)
    {
        _configuraiton = configuraiton.Value;
    }
}
```

3.) Add `MyClass` as a parameter of the `AnotherClass` constructor. Dependency Injection will create the `MyClass` or reuse it depending on the scope of the object and how you setup that up in the `Startup.ConfifureServices()` method.

```
public class AnotherClass
{

    private MyClass _myclass;

    public AnoherClass(MyClass myclass)
    {
        _myclass= myclass;
    }

    public SomeMethod()
    {

       //Use myClass here and you don't need to instantiate it.
       _myclass
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You doing a couple of things.

1 - You are re-declaring your class variable `myclass` as a local variable in your `SomeMethod`. You should use the `myclass` variable you already declared as a class variable. To do that, make this line

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass(_configuration);
```

Like this

```
myclass = new MyClass(_configuration);
```

2 - You are not instantiating your `IConfigurationRoot`, so it is null before inject it at all. You should be able to instantiate it however you want (`ConfigurationBuilder` like @Sach suggested, or `_configuration = ConfigurationBuilder.Build()` as @Eldho suggested), but you need to instantiate it before you inject it if you dont want it to be null.

Comment: Well passing it in manually as a parameter isn't _"injection"_

Answer (score 0):

Here, it would be best if you use an IOC container like Autofac or Unity or the built-in container in ASP.NET core(if you are using core). You would need to register your IConfigurationRoot interface and its implemented class with the IOC container. After this, inject your MyClass object using the IOC container(in the constructor, or in the method, as per your best scenario). This way, you would never face a problem.

Comment: ....as opposed to just going `_configuration = ConfigurationBuilder.Build()`?   IoC are an example of mass psychosis

Comment: I inferred the problem was related to avoid passing null dependencies, and instantiate objects at the right place. I did not suggest on how to create the configuration object. _configuration = ConfigurationBuilder.Build() would still be needed.