# SignalR Dependency Injection in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am quite new to SignalR and trying to create a Chat application using SignalR v1.0.0-alpha2-final in Asp.Net Core 2.0, and have a need to use dependency injection in the ChatHub. All the examples I  have found seems to either be outdated or not related to Asp.Net Core.

Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Edit: To clarify, I know how to do DI en Asp.Net Core, the problem is I don`t know how to do it in the SignalR Hub.

Comment: Why not create a wrapper to SignalR with a class/interface and use that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SignalR, there is a `SignalRAppBuilderExtensions` class that gives you the `UseSignalR` method.

In `Startup.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<YourHub>("/yourhub");
    }
 }
```

Then just business as usual

```
 public class YourHub: Hub
 {
     public YourHub(Stuff stuff)
     {
     }
 }
```

Version: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0-preview1-final

Comment: This works, thank you!

Comment: What about the issue on [SignalR dependency injection using Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222574/signalr-dependency-injection-using-ninject#comment100955421_57222574)? Any idea about that? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

In .NET Core 2, the dependency injection, comes as a feature - you don't need to add packages like Unity etc. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) is the official documentation.

Basically, when having a .NET Core application, you have the entry point `Program.cs` and the `Startup.cs` files, that are executed on the initial start of the application.

The 'magic' with dependency injection happens in the `Startup.cs`. There (by default) you have

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 /// code
}
```

To add an injection you need to do something like:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyInterface, MyClassImplementingMyInterface>();
```

Except `AddTransient` there are 2 more possibilities, defining the lifetime of your service. They are: `AddSingleton` and `AddScoped`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/what-is-the-difference-between-services-addtransient-service-addscope-and-servi) answer, and the documentation, that I mentioned above, give a good explanation of the meaning of all of them, but in a few words:

> Depending on how we configure the lifetime for this service, the
>   container will provide either the same or different instances of the
>   service to the requesting class.

- `AddTransient` - the objects are always different; a new instance is
  provided to every controller and every service.
- `AddScoped` - the    objects are the same within a request, but
  different across different    requests
- `AddSingleton` - the objects are the same for every object
  and every request (regardless of whether an instance is provided in
  ConfigureServices)

Comment: Thanks, my problem is not directly related to Dependency Injection alone, as I have that covered for every other aspect of the project, the problem is the "standard" way of doing this does not work for signalr hub. From what I´ve read _"The only problem is that a SignalR application does not directly create hubs; SignalR creates them for you. By default, SignalR expects a hub class to have a parameterless constructor. "_ [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection]. But this documentation, although it is regarding signalr, it is not for .net core.

Comment: I see, sorry I missed that. Well what about this - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/