# Adding a custom singleton that is unique for each request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I've been struggling to figure out the dependency pattern that comes with asp net core. Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

**_ViewImports.cshtml**

```
...    
@inject AdminBuilder AdminBuilder
...
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddHttpContextIshSingleton<AdminBuilder>();
    ...
}
```

**AnyCSHtmlFile.cshtml**

```
@AdminBuilder.AddStuff()
@AdminBuilder.EnableStuff()
@AdminBuilder.DoStuff()
// It'll then populate the AdminBuilder instance, which needs to be a unique instance for each visit.
```

**Layout.cshtml**

Here I'll render the AdminBuilder at the bottom from a partial .cshtml file, based on what's been added while rendering the page.

Comment: Perhaps View components can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: What is exactly the problem with the "scoped" scope? It resolves only once every http request, so it is singleton in the scope of the http request.

Comment: @PeterHurtony Nothing, nothing at all! Scoped was exactly what I was looking for! You're welcome to add an answer with that. Thanks a lot.

The API documentation for all of them says the same. "Adds a scoped services of the type specified in the serviceType to the specified IServiceCollectrion". So it's a bit hard figured out what it is you actually need. Any article or documentation, in particular, you would recommend reading up on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between services.AddTransient, service.AddScoped and service.AddSingleton methods in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/what-is-the-difference-between-services-addtransient-service-addscoped-and-serv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `services.AddScoped<AdminBuilder>()`.

You can read more about the built in lifetimes in the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#service-lifetimes