# ASP.NET Core Singleton instance vs Transient instance performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

In ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection, I just wonder if registering `Singleton` instances will improve performance instead of registering `Transient` instances or not?

In my thinking, for `Singleton` instance, it just costs once time for creating new object and dependent objects. For `Transient` instance, this cost will be repeated for each service request. So `Singleton` seems to be better. But how much performance do we gain when using `Singleton` over `Transient`?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it's not the case of better or worse and yes a case of the right one, that depends a lot when talking about dependency injection

Comment: This is not a matter of performance. You should use the solution that you need.

Comment: I agree with @Silvermind's sentiment, however, you may prefer prefer to use `Singleton` instead of `Transient` in situations where the observable behavior isn't impacted to reduce the overhead of object construction and graph traversal.  However, like all optimizations, you should measure to see whether this matters at all.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim, thank you for the reply. In my case, both Singleton or Transient is OK for using, so I consider to choose the better performance. Singleton can cause leaking of memory, but I think it is better performance.

Comment: @Silvermind, thank you. Did you measure the performance of them or is there any link refer to this?

Comment: @Matthew, thank you. You meant Singleton will be better performance? As you said, I should measure to see.

Comment: It can be, in scenarios where you have very deep dependency graphs or scenarios where the initialization of the dependencies are expensive, at the expense of memory.

Answer (score 67):

Like others have said, performance should not make your decision here: performance will not be dramatically impacted either way. What should be your consideration is dependencies, both managed and unmanaged. Singletons are best when you're utilizing limited resources, like sockets and connections. If you end up having to create a new socket every time the service is injected (transient), then you'll quickly run out of sockets and then performance really will be impacted.

Transient scope is better when resource usage is temporary and of minimal impact. If you're only doing computation, for instance, that can be transient scoped because you're not exhausting anything by having multiple copies.

You also want to use singleton scope when state matters. If something needs to persist past one particular operation, then transient won't work, because you'll have no state, because it will essentially start over each time it's injected. For example, if you were trying to coordinate a concurrent queue, using semaphores for locks, then you'd definitely want a singleton scoped service. If state doesn't matter, then transient is probably the better scope.

Finally, you must look at other services your service has a dependency on. If you need access to scoped services (such as things that are request-scoped), then a singleton is a bad fit. While you can possibly use a service-locator pattern to access the scoped services, that's a faux pas, and not recommended. Basically, if your service uses anything but other singleton services, it should likely be scoped or transient instead.

Long and short, use a transient scope unless you have a good, explicit reason to make it a singleton. That would be reasons like mentioned above: maintaining state, utilizing limited resources efficiently, etc. If the service will work in a transient scope, and there's no good reason to do otherwise, use transient scope.

Now, ASP.NET Core's DI has both a "transient" and a "scoped" lifetime. Both of these are "transient" in the sense that they come and go, but "scoped" is instantiated once per "scope" (usually a request), whereas "transient" is *always* instantiated every time it is injected. Here, you should use "scoped" unless you have a good, explicit reason to use "transient".

Comment: +1 for your explanation. However, I kind of confused with the last statement on transient vs scoped per transaction. Microsoft states that "Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services."That means for REST api it is recommended to use transient?

Comment: It's talking about the service you're injecting, not the "service" as in an entire API. My point was that you should pretty much just always use `AddScoped` unless you have a specific use case that actually warrants using the other methods like `AddSingleton` or `AddTransient` to register your services.

Comment: Great answer! But let me note, that there is a class of services where the simple rule "Scoped is best if no other reasons exist" may mislead you. This is especially true for .NET Core's own services. For example you would think that AddScoped is perfect for the HttpContextAccessor service. But it is not. You should use `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` in this case. Bottomline: Check the docs (or StackOverflow) for the correct lifetime of any services that you did not write yourself!

Comment: In my case, using transient instead of Singleton, causes an overhead of at least 200ms. And I don't have a single constructor that does anything else that field assignment. But there are a handful of classes that need to be created. Since its a chatbot service, every ms is visible on the user. There are cases, where a call becomes 5x slower. So there are cases, where performance matters.

Comment: Does the DI system instantiate the controller at each request or is the controller singleton?

Comment: @Konstantine a 200ms overhead does not sound right to me. I really think there must be something really wrong going on with your services if that's the difference you are observing on transient vs singleton.

Comment: @variable controller is instantiated for each request, unless you request them to be registered in DI and configure separately. By default, controllers are not instantiated from DI, but created by ASP.NET and each of their ctor params is taken from DI (as well as method params with [FromServices] attribute)

Answer (score 5):

I know that the performance here is not what you should looking for, but for a matter of curiosity, I made a sample benchmark app to evaluate the difference between AddSingleton and AddTransient, using BenchmarkDotNet

The solution that I used can be found here (Feel free to improve it): https://github.com/iheb719/BenchmarkDifferentServicesInstances

This was my summary :

**My laptop specifications :**
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19042.1415 (20H2/October2020Update)
Intel Core i7-9750H CPU 2.60GHz, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.101
[Host]     : .NET 6.0.1 (6.0.121.56705), X64 RyuJIT
DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.1 (6.0.121.56705), X64 RyuJIT

**My results** :

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CallSingletonApp | 101.0 us | 0.64 us | 0.53 us |
| CallTransientApp | 108.3 us | 1.16 us | 1.03 us |

So there is really **no significant difference** between AddSingleton and AddTransient (of course, if you don't have huge treatments inside your constructors)

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the replies this isn't really a matter over performance.

For more details please see the link below where the difference is very elaborately explained.
[AddTransient, AddScoped and AddSingleton Services Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences/38139500#38139500)

The only way that this will matter performance wise is if your constructor is doing a lot of stuff. This can and should be avoided though in all cases.

Comment: thank you for the reply. In my case, I consider performance and leaking memory when using Singleton over Transient. Of course, both of them can be applied in my case.

Comment: Well like mentioned there, and in other comments here it is not just up to performance. The performance gain or difference within your application will be massively dependent on the further context of your application. The only way to really verify this is to actually run your scenario and test it and even then,,,,,
There are probably plenty of other things that will give you a more significant performance improvent.