# EF Core memory leak if get DbContext with no scope

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, memory-leaks

I have a problem with my ASP.NET Core application (.NET 7, EF Core 7, Npgsql PostgreSQL 7).

As an example, I wrote a simple web service that reproduces the problem:

1. In the controller in a loop we get the context from the ServiceProvider, we see a memory leak:

   [image]
2. The same thing, but with the creation of scope - no memory leak:

   [image]

Why is this happening? Is creating a scope the only correct solution?

Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }

    public TestController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    private const int IterationsCount = 20_000;

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Leak()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < IterationsCount; i++)
        {
            using var context = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestContext>();
            var a = await context.TestEntitys.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        GC.Collect();

        return Ok("There is leak");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> NoLeak()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < IterationsCount; i++)
        {
            using var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope();
            using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestContext>();
            var a = await context.TestEntitys.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        GC.Collect();

        return Ok("There is NO leak");
    }
}
```

Context:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TestEntity> TestEntitys { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class TestEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(opts =>
{
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(typeof(TestContext).Name);
    opts.UseNpgsql(connectionString).UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

var app = builder.Build();

var context = app.Services.GetRequiredService<TestContext>();
await context.Database.MigrateAsync();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EFCore.NamingConventions" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.15">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.15">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: in the "leak" example, I think the "context" will be disposed at the end of the scope in which it's declared, in this case the end of the "for", try to use "using" with curly brackets like this: using(){} inside the "for".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Dbcontext registered as "scoped" or "transient" affect in closing database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57659980/does-dbcontext-registered-as-scoped-or-transient-affect-in-closing-database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two examples will have quite different behaviours based on the fact that you are scoping your DbContext as Transient.

In the first example using the common injected scope, if you have 20,000 iterations you will be instantiating 20,000 instances of the DbContext, each tracking the entity being loaded. Those contexts will not be collected until the request scope is collected. While you are disposing each DbContext instance within the loop, the lifetime scope still tracks a reference to Transient instances so the GC will only release them once the scope is disposed.

In the second example you are constructing and disposing an inner scope within each iteration. This means that in this case the outer scope is tracking references of each inner scope, but within each iteration a single DbContext instance is created, disposed, and can be collected as the scope within the iteration itself is disposed, releasing any references.

The memory use for the first example would more closely match the second if switched to using a shared lifetime scope rather than transient. There would be a difference in behavior though in that requests for the same item within the loop would return tracked instances unless queried with `AsNoTracking` or disabling tracking on the DbContext.

Edit: Something to try to confirm the references being hung onto:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> NoLeak2()
{
    using (var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < IterationsCount; i++)
        {
            using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestContext>();
            var a = await context.TestEntitys.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
    }
    GC.Collect();

    return Ok("There is NO leak?");
}
```

I suspect this will work with an explicitly scoped  `using() {}` for the scope, but if you were to use an implicitly scoped `using();` or tried moving the `GC.Collect();` and `return` inside the `using` scope you would see the same apparent memory usage if inspecting on a breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I'll try to dig deeper. Could you please provide an any link to a more detailed "Those contexts will not be collected until the request scope is collected" ? This kind of behavior, to be honest, is unexpected and confusing to me

Comment: It is related to how garbage collection works. Memory is only released when all references are released. IoC containers like ServiceProvider maintain references for every instance they provide, even Transient ones (Which only determines if the container creates a new instance for each request or passes the same reference to subsequent requests) For ASP.Net MVC the lifetime of the service provider is the Request so any instances that service provider creates will not be de-referenced until the provider is disposed at the end of the request.

Comment: I added a variation you could try to verify the disposal behavior and implications on the garbage collection. With a using bound scope outside of the loop that is disposed before the `GC.Collect` I suspect you will find everything cleaned up, but if the `GC.Collect` falls inside the scope (moved inside or using `using();` it will likely exhibit the same leak-like beavior when inspected.