# How approach is better to register services Dependency Injection in .Net Core

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to understand how the Dependency Injection service registry works. I have a generic repository that does database operations for any table such as GetAll(), GetById() ... 
and another service that will commit to the database. such as Save(); Commit();

I have read 
[AddTransient, AddScoped and AddSingleton Services Differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences)

My question is what would be the best option to register the Generic Repository service and Db service and why?

```
services.AddScoped (typeof (IRepository<>), typeof (Repository<>));
services.AddTransient (typeof (IRepository<>), typeof (Repository<>));
services.AddSingleton (typeof (IRepository<>), typeof (Repository<>));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AddScoped` . Scoped services are created per scope. In a web application, every web request creates a new separated service scope. That means scoped services are generally created per web request.

If you're calling db multiple times in the same request, then use scoped lifetime will help keeping the same repository object in the memory and reuses that multiple times within the same Http Request context. If using transient , it will creates a new repository object multiple times and consumes more memory .