# Connection string property has not been initialized Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

Facing this exception message in my GenericRepository

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

I have already configured my connection in `Startup.cs` like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

I have another query where I am calling stored procedure and its fetching records. But when I am accessing DB from EF it's throwing this error.

NOTE: I have written a UNIT Test for this piece of code and it works and fetch records from DB.

Stack Trace

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__45.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferlessMoveNext>d__12.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__11.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.d__7.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Select.cs:line 106
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.d__10.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\AsyncIterator.cs:line 98
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.d__6`3.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Aggregate.cs:line 120
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Repositories.GenericRepository`1.d__9.MoveNext() in 
>   Repositories\Implementations\GenericRepository.cs:line 122

Comment: what's the value of  Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?

Comment: The value is `"Server=.;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0;Integrated Security=SSPI;"`

Comment: @gsharp I have created a unit test to test my repository method and its working fine, giving no exceptions

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was calling a SPROC before my repository, I calling SPROC in old fashion way. Got the connection string from `context.Database.GetConnectionString()` and using that variable in a using statement and that statement was wrapped in a try catch finally block. After my SPROC was executed I manually close the connection. Which cause the exception at the repository level. Once I closed the connection string EF would not be able to connect to the DB as its connection was disposed of in using statement.

I found 2 simple solution
 1. (Recommended) I made the SPROC return multiple tables so that I don't have to call the repository again.
 2. (Not Recommended) I update the `Stratup.cs` from `services.AddScoped<DbContext, DataContext>();` to `services.AddTransient<DbContext, DataContext>();`. If you are not familiar with this option I higly recommend not using it. [Have a look at this link for further clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences)