# what is the purpose of registering the same service more than once?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I recently run upon a net core project with the current configuration:

```
services.AddTransient<Service1>();
services.AddSingleton<Service1>();
```

Where `Service1` was a class. What could possibly be the purpose of this? Or its just a mistake?
Is there any way to choose whether to use a new instance of the service or the singleton dynamically?

Comment: You can check your question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences

Comment: I know the diferences. I was wandering why there are used BOTH

Comment: It is literally like that? I only imagine the usage in runtime when the context has been changed somehow and you need to use a singleton

Comment: Literally except the class name

Comment: So this is a mistake probably, IoC would use Singleton registration as the last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last registration "wins" so your `Service1` type will be registered as a singleton given your current code.

If you change the order of the calls, it's going to be registered as a transient dependency. But don't do both. Choose one lifetime per type.

Comment: adding to the above, if you use TryAdd instead of Add, it will keep the first registration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.extensions.servicecollectiondescriptorextensions.tryadd?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1