# How to return a list of employees in Controller, Given a boolean parameter, fx api/employees?hasOvertime=true

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created an employee class and EmployeeWebSerivce,

I need to create a controller class which exposes three HTTP endpoints:
api/employees (GET)

Returning a list of all employees. Given a boolean parameter ‘hasOvertime’, the endpoint should be able to filter the list of Employees using the EmployeeService.  E.g.: api/employees?hasOvertime=true.

api/employees (POST)

Taking an Employee object in the request body and storing it in the list of employees.

api/payments (GET)

Returning the sum of all monthly payments. Similar to the other GET method, you should be able to filter by overtime, given a boolean parameter.

I don't know how to call methods from EmployeeWebService class.

```
 public class Employee
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public double HourlyWage { get; set; }
    public double HoursPerMonth { get; set; }
    public double GetMonthlyPay()
    {

        double overTimeHours= HoursPerMonth - 150;
        double pay;

        if(overTimeHours <= 0)
        {
            pay = HourlyWage * HoursPerMonth;
        }
        else
        {
            pay = (150 * HourlyWage) + (overTimeHours * HourlyWage * 1.5);
        }
        return pay;


    }
```

EmployeeWebService

```
public class EmployeeWebService
{

    private List<Employee> FilterEmployeeBasedOnOverTime(List<Employee> employee, bool hasOvertime = false)
    {
        return employee.Where(e => hasOvertime ? e.HoursPerMonth > 150 : e.HoursPerMonth <= 150).ToList();


    }
    private double GetTotalMonthlyExpense(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        return employees.Sum(e => e.GetMonthlyPay());
    }
```

Comment: Are you using .Net Core? You could instantiate the EmployeeWebService in the controller but that would make testing a nightmare. So i would use Dependency Injection. In .Net Core this is built in but if you are using ASP Net 5 you could use Autofac

Comment: I am using .net Core. can you help me a little that how I should use Dependency Injection?
 Thanks

Comment: I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to the Community SJcoder.
So because you are using .NET Core you can use Dependency Injection. If you are unfamiliar with the concept see this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Also i changed your "GetMonthlyTotalExpense" from double to decimal. See why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)

First you will want an interface of IEmployeeWebService. This will look like the below:

```
 public interface IEmployeeWebService
 {
    List<Employee> FilterEmployeeBasedOnOverTime(List<Employee> employee, bool hasOvertime = false);
    decimal GetTotalMonthlyExpense(List<Employee> employees);
 }
```

Then you have to implement this interface. So the implementing class will look like the below:

```
  public class EmployeeWebService : IEmployeeWebService
  {
    public List<Employee> FilterEmployeeBasedOnOverTime(List<Employee> employee, bool hasOvertime = false)
    {
        return employee.Where(e => hasOvertime ? e.HoursPerMonth > 150 : e.HoursPerMonth <= 150).ToList();

    }

    public decimal GetTotalMonthlyExpense(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        return employees.Sum(e => e.GetMonthlyPay());
    }
  }
```

Then you have to tell the DI Container what class the interface is going to resolve to. You may be wondering what "AddScoped<>()" does. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences), it helped me understand. Your startup class will look like the below:

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
        services.AddScoped<IEmployeeWebService, EmployeeWebService>();
     }
```

And now in you controller you can use the service and its methods like so:

```
    public HomeController(IEmployeeWebService employeeWebService)
    {
        _employeeWebService = employeeWebService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Models.Employee> filteredResults = _employeeWebService.FilterEmployeeBasedOnOverTime(employees, true);
        return View(filteredResults);
    }
```

I don't know how you are getting your employees but if you are getting them from the database then you can pass that as a parameter to the service. I hope this helps and any questions please comment :)

Comment: Thanks Daniaal and thanks for detailed explanation.
i read all the links which were really helpful.
learned alot.

Comment: @SJcoder No problem. You got to start from somewhere. Anything else you want to know just comment and i will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the controller class like this:

```
var controller = new EmployeeWebService();
```

Then you can call the methods like this:

```
var result = controller.FilterEmployeeBasedOnOverTime(someEmployee, false);
```

The problem you will run in to though is that your methods are private and therefore you can't call them from a different class. You can read more on access modifiers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Comment: Hey Karly, can you explain your code? and someEmployee