# How to avoid repeating conditional logic?

Tags: c#, .net-core, delegates, func, code-reuse

I'm implementing security features for my .NET Core application and I'm finding myself repeating the same conditional logic over and over. 
Is there a way where I can generalize this in one place and have it applied to the segments I want?
I recall using delegates or Func for this type of thing but I'm not quite sure... Any ideas?

Below is the code I'm trying to write once and apply in multiple places.

```cs
var currentUser = _httpContext.HttpContext.Session.GetCurrentUser<SessionContext>();
if(currentUser.Roles.Any())
{
    // ex query here. This could be any piece of code
    var q = from u in _dbContext.Users
            join d in _dbContext.Users on u.DoctorId equals d.Id into ud
            from docU in ud.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                User = u,
                Doctor = docU
            };

    if(!currentUser.Roles.Contains("Administrator"))
    {
        if(currentUser.Roles.Contains("Doctor"))
        {
            //do something here
           //ex.
           q = q.Where(x => (x.Doctor != null ? x.Doctor.Id == currentUserId : false));
        }
        else if (currentUser.Roles.Contains("Patient"))
        {
            //do something else here
            //ex.
            q = q.Where(x => x.User.Id == currentUserId);
        }
    }
}
else
    throw new Exception("No roles applied to logged in user");
```

Comment: Are you saying you're having this particular block of code in multiple places, or are you fretting over the multiple if-statements in this single block of code?

Comment: I am having this block of code in multiple places. I'm not too worried about the multiple if-statements.

Comment: it is hard to know what could change without having an idea of what you are doing in your If statements. If this was for an API on the controller methods you could add an Authorize attribute like ```[Authorize(Roles = "Doctor", "Patient")]```

Comment: I'm writing linq queries inside my if-statements. But I guess my objective is to write anything inside those if statements but maintain the outer logic. I've updated my example. Cheers!

Comment: I think you should take a look at Specification pattern in c#

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new `service`.

```
public class MyHttpContextService : IMyHttpContextService
{
    IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

    public MyHttpContextService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    public string CheckUserRoles()
    {
        try
        {
            var currentUser = _httpContext?.HttpContext?.Session?.GetCurrentUser<SessionContext>();
            if (currentUser != null)
            {
                if(currentUser.Roles.Any())
                {
                    if(!currentUser.Roles.Contains("Administrator"))
                    {
                        if(currentUser.Roles.Contains("Doctor"))
                        {
                            //do something here
                        }
                        else if (currentUser.Roles.Contains("Patient"))
                        {
                            //do something else here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // if currentUser == null
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // exception handling
        }

    }
}
```

Notice the line

```
var currentUser = _httpContext.HttpContext.Session.GetCurrentUser<SessionContext>();
```

is replaced by

```
var currentUser = _httpContext?.HttpContext?.Session?.GetCurrentUser<SessionContext>();
```

Create appropriate `interface`.

```
public interface IMyHttpContextService
{
    string CheckUserRoles();
}
```

In this example `string` is return type, but it does not need to be.

Finally, register this service using line

```
services.AddScoped<IMyHttpContextService, MyHttpContextService>();
```

where `services` is

```
IServiceCollection services
```

Instead of `AddScoped`, you could use `AddTransient`, or `AddSingleton`. [More about objects' lifetime and dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences). These three keywords determine the lifetime of an object, or in this case, of service.

Registration is starting in `Startup.cs` (but to be honest, everything is starting in `Startup.cs`, hence the name). [More about Startup.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1). In other words, in `Startup.cs` call method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

which is called by runtime.

Inside method `ConfigureServices` call another one, for instance `MapInterfaces`, for interface mapping and pass it `services`. Method `MapInterfaces` will be a `static` method inside `ServiceExtensions.cs`.

```
public static void MapInterfaces(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IMyHttpContextService, MyHttpContextService>();
}
```

Even better is to create an **extension** method [More about extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method).

`ServiceExtensions.cs` is a `static` class, which is a condition for creating extension method. Extension method also needs to be `static`. This would be the methods signature

```
static void MapInterfaces(this IServiceCollection services)
```

Of course, don't forget the access modifier (at least the same visibility as the `ServiceExtensions.cs` class). Notice `this` keyword.

Extension method `MapInterfaces` from `ServiceExtensions.cs` is then called inside `ConfigureServices` method from `Startup.cs` like this

```
services.MapInterfaces();
```

In the end, whenever you need method `CheckUserRoles`, call it like this

```
_myHttpContextService.CheckUserRoles();
```

**EDIT**: You've changed the implementation of method, but that doesn't change the way you could do the rest of solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code written in Swift.
I'm using functional oriented programming, with dictionaries

---

```
struct User {
    var Roles: Set<String> = ["Doctor"]
}

func channel(user: User, _ roles: [String:() -> ()]) {
    for i in roles {
        if user.Roles.contains(i.key) { i.value() }
    }
}

let currentUser = User()
channel(user: currentUser,
       [
        "Doctor": {
        // Code for doctor
        },

        "Admin": {
        // Code for admin
        },

        "Blah": {
        // Code for blah
        },

        // You can even add more
    ]
)
```

You can enum Create an Enum
Why an Enum?
You can easily make typos with regular Strings
With an Enum, if you make a typo, Swift gives you an error. Super Helpful!

```
enum UserRolls { case doctor, admin, patient, other(String) }
extension UserRolls: Hashable {}

struct User {
    var Roles: Set<UserRolls> = [.doctor]
}

func channel(user: User, _ roles: [UserRolls:() -> ()]) {
    for i in roles {
        if user.Roles.contains(i.key) { i.value() }
    }
}

let currentUser = User()
channel(user: currentUser,
       [
        .doctor: {
        // Code for doctor
        },

        .admin: {
        // Code for admin
        },

        .other("Blah"): {
        // Code for blah
        },

        // You can even add more
    ]
)
```