# How to pass default params to ASP .Net Core controllers?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm not really familiar that much about `ASP.Net Core`. My issue is I have this controller like the following

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : MyBaseService
{
    private IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    private IAuth _auth;

    public MyController(IWebHostEnvironment env,
                                IAuth auth) : base(auth)
    {
        _hostingEnv = env;
        _auth = auth;
    }
```

`IAuth` is registered as Scoped service in `Startup.cs` like `services.AddScoped<IAut, Auth>();` If I call the controller, the `auth` doesn't have values. I believe this is because of the lifetime of the service, am I right? If that is so. I just want to populate it with values whenever the controller is being called. Is there such a way like getting the values from `IAuth` then automatically insert it in the level of `Startup.cs` something like this lambda function?

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
      SupportedCultures = "String value here.",
});
```

If my imagination is wrong just correct me as I said I'm not that familiar with ASP.Net Core.

Comment: did you see this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#lifetime-and-registration-options could be the answer is in there

Comment: I see a problem: the name of the constructor must be the same name as the controller class. MyController is the name of your controller but your constructor is called FileUploadController. You call base but i don't think it knows about IAuth..also what does IAuth do? the dependency injection works like when you request the interface you get an implemplementation of it. So that Auth class is where you have your data and methods ready to use in your controller by using IAuth. It will have what data you have in your Auth class.

Comment: Sorry @Johan, it was a mistyped. I already corrected it.

Comment: @sommmen haven't read it yet. I'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some properties on the `Auth` service that you need to be set during the registration, you can use the `AddScoped` like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IAut, Auth>(sb => new Auth() { SomeValue = "value" });
```

Answer (score 0):

The method @kebek provided is in the right direction, but you need to populate the data according to `the structure in your Auth class`.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences).

Here is my demo:

```
public interface IAuth
    {
        string MyValue{ get; }
    }

 public class Auth: IAuth
    {
        string _value; 
        public Auth(string value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public string MyValue=> _value;
    }
```

In startup.cs:

```
 services.AddScoped<IAuth, Auth>(provider => new Auth("Your value"));
```

Here is the result:

[image]