# ASP.net. services.AddTransient<JsonFileChampService>();

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
services.AddTransient<JsonFileChampService>();
```

Does anyone know what the the less than and greater than symbols do after the method name but before the ()?

JsonFileChampService is a .cs file.

In general, what does the '< >' do in C#/.Net/ ASP.net?

Thank you!

Comment: Besides `JsonFileChampService` being a cs file, it is also a class that is used to initialize the transient method via AddTransient method of `Type` `JsonFileChampService`. [Read here for Transient method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38139500/1390548)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the link!

Comment: Search online for `c# generics`. Plenty of documentation to find on it

Answer (score 0):

In general, what does the '< >' do in C#/.Net/ ASP.net?

'<>' symbol defines a type.

For example you want to initialise a list of integers:

var listInt = new List();

Or a list of an object:
var listObj = new List();

So it defines that the list we are initialising has integers or objects.
As for your sample attached it defines that you add a service of type JsonFileChampService.