# OWin Appbuilder rebuilding the app 70 -125 times per event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I've been following several tutorial on integrating the OWin identity in my ASP.net app, for instance [this one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity/)

So my StartupLogin now has the method

```
public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(Application‌​RoleManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
    [...]
```

to create (and I quote the link) "a per-request, single instance of the UserManager and DbContext classes from the OWIN context to be used throughout the application."

But I saw very weird calling behavior to the `Create` functions, so I added the class

```
class DebugManager : IDisposable
{
    private static int count = 0;
    public static DebugManager Create() { Debug.WriteLine($"Owin Build called {count++};"); return new DebugManager(); }
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

and the line

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(DebugManager.Create);
```

Looking at the debug window, I saw that the `Create()` methods are called **74** times on initial application startup, and **120-124(!!!!)** times on other actions like login, page refresh, logout, etc, etc...

That cannot be the way it should work, right? A `create` function should only be called once, where after you can get the instance of the object via the `OWinContext.Get<>`, right? What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/owincontext-and-why-you-can-have-many-of-them/)

> ## Dependency Injection in Owin
>
> ... each time the OwinContext is pulled from the HttpContext, it returns a new context ... if we are applying DI terms here, then your object is registered in **per-request scope**, as you would expect to be DbContext.

And I recently learned the difference between "transient", "scoped" and "singleton" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38139500).

It turns out a page request of our (very large) project (in development mode, where caching of static files is off) causes 125 requests to server, which caused the issue.