# I would like to know more about services.AddTransient<Func<DbConnection, IIntegrationEventLogService>>()?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am studying the eShopOnContainers project on Microsoft. here is a line that injects `IIntegrationEventLogService`in startup via this line:

```
services.AddTransient<Func<DbConnection, IIntegrationEventLogService>>(
                sp => (DbConnection c) => new IntegrationEventLogService(c));
```

you can also see the whole class and project [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/d0cd2830a864a8b975341b02b93a0887a3908c04/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Startup.cs#L273) on Github.

I would like to know the reason for using `<Func<DbConnection, IIntegrationEventLogService>>(  sp => (DbConnection c) => new IntegrationEventLogService(c))`  and some declaration about syntax!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AddTransient, AddScoped and AddSingleton Services Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences)

Comment: @MindSwipe No, That's not my question! I ask about func<> in transient and other sections of code! I know exactly about AddScope and AddTransient and Add Singletone!

Comment: I mean, then it's even easier. Check out the [`Func<T, TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0) class which is part of .NET Core

Comment: @MindSwipe Dear friend, I even know about Func<>! But it's hard for me to find out that code purpose! You know! I want to know why use this complex type instead of a simple one?  like AddTransient<X,IX>() ?

Comment: Well, it's adding a transient function, which when called will return a new `IntegraiontEventLogService`, it's a factory function. Using GitHub's search function to search for uses of  `Func<DbConnection, IIntegrationEventLogService>` in the code results [this](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/5e0f55cbd92842445747a50f35c467d972ba80f9/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/Application/IntegrationEvents/OrderingIntegrationEventService.cs#L25) showing the usage

Comment: @MindSwipe Thanks, your declaration was useful. But also I need more investigation on this code!