# How is the PageModel(razor pages) dispose?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I want to dispose EF context on `PageModel`(**razor page**) but `PageModel` class does not have `Dispose` method like Controller ?

Comment: Why do you want to dispose the EF context? Normally this is handled by the dependecy injection system. How do you retrive the context?

Comment: I got it, no need then

Comment: This is a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences