# .Net Core Dependency injection services.Add vs services.Replace

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

What is the difference between injecting a service using services.(AddScoped, AddTransient, AddSingleton) and the service.replace for example

```
services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>, SqlPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>();
```

```
services.Replace(new ServiceDescriptor(
    serviceType: typeof(IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>),
    implementationType: typeof(SqlPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>),
        ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
```

Comment: Well, `Replace()` will _replace_ any previously registered service of that service type, so if there was one already registered it would be removed. `Add()` _adds_ another one, so if there was one there before, there'd now be two.

Comment: There is already an answer. Please search before asking a new question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences

Comment: @İbrahimULUDAĞ My question is highly different i am asking the difference between service.add and service.replace actually not the types in add, Please read the question carefully before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

The difference can be seen in  the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/src/Extensions/ServiceCollectionDescriptorExtensions.cs).

The first one is the `IServiceCollection` interface, a core interface of the dependency injection.

```cs
public interface IServiceCollection : IList<ServiceDescriptor>
{
}
```

`IServiceCollection` is just a list of `ServiceDescriptor` objects. `ServiceDescriptor` describes the information of the injected types.

Based on this interface, the two methods `Add` and `Replace` can be discussed.

```cs
public static IServiceCollection Add(
            this IServiceCollection collection,
            ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
{
    ...
    collection.Add(descriptor);
    return collection;
}

public static IServiceCollection Replace(
            this IServiceCollection collection,
            ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
{
    ...
    // Remove existing
    int count = collection.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (collection[i].ServiceType == descriptor.ServiceType)
        {
            collection.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    collection.Add(descriptor);
    return collection;
}
```

`Add` just pushes the service descriptor into the list, while `Replace` firstly checks and deletes the descriptors in the list with the same service type, and finally add the current descriptor to the list.

Therefore, the time complexities of these two methods are different. The time complexity of `Add` in most cases is O(1), while `Replace` is O(n) (traverse the list). However, `Add` does not guarantee that the added descriptor is unique, but `Replace` will delete the descriptors with the same service type and add the current one.