# DI Issue when trying to get Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

so I am having some DI issues which I do not understand. I saw a few posts similar and I tried what they recommended but I have not had any luck. Here is the error I am getting

> "Unable to resolve service for type 'IRetrieveService' while
> attempting to activate 'UpdateService'

Here is how I have my update service setup

```cs
private readonly IAsyncPolicy<SaveDocumentsResult> _processDocumentUpdatesPolicy;
private readonly IRetrieveService _retrieveService;
private readonly ISaveService _saveService;

public UpdateService(
    IAsyncPolicy<SaveDocumentsResult> processDocumentUpdatesPolicy,
    IRetrieveService retrieveService,
    ISaveService saveService)
{
    _processDocumentUpdatesPolicy = processDocumentUpdatesPolicy ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(processDocumentUpdatesPolicy));
    _retrieveService = retrieveService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(retrieveService));
    _saveService = saveService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(saveService));
}
```

Finally, I have this where I have added my services

```cs
Services.AddScoped<IRetrieveService, RetrieveService>();
Services.AddScoped<ISaveService, SaveService>();
```

Comment: Can you show how you have registered `UpdateService` in DI? Can you show the definition of `RetrieveService` (at least the constructor), _and any dependencies it has_? Can you post the full stack-trace?

Comment: This registration looks ok. It's the RegistrationService class that possibly is missing some of its dependencies

Comment: Try adding the services as singletons (temporarily) to see if that helps. Maybe that will lead you to a better solution.

Comment: Also, and I know this seems obvious, but are the `AddScoped` calls actually being made?

Comment: Can you post the relates code about IRetrieveService and the RetrieveService? Besides, about the UpdateService Constructor method, have you ever registered the UpdateService class?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `Services.AddScoped<IRetrieveService, RetrieveService>()` and see if it's actually being hit. If so, double check whether the the registration is made on a `Services` instance that is *later on* used to build the `IServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your code suggest any issues regarding the IRetreiverService and implementation. I believe there must be at problem with your service setup.

Try have a look at the following link. It describes the different usages.

[AddTransient, AddScoped and AddSingleton Services Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences)