# MudBlazor - Show snackbar from a HTTP message handler

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have a HTTP interceptor that catches network connectivity errors:

```cs
public class NetworkErrorInterceptor : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ISnackbar snackbar;

    public NetworkErrorInterceptor(ISnackbar snackbar)
    {
        this.snackbar = snackbar;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // ...

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Network Interceptor: sending request");
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Network Interceptor: inside catch block");
            snackbar.Add("Network connection error", Severity.Error, config =>
            {
                // ...
            });
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

When this logic was inside a component I could see the [snackbar](https://mudblazor.com/components/snackbar#usage), but when I moved it to the interceptor it doesn't work anymore. I moved it because it needs to be applied to all requests. I can see the console messages though.

DI:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<NetworkErrorInterceptor>();
builder.Services
    .AddHttpClient(/* ... */)
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<NetworkErrorInterceptor>();
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on a Grpc interceptor, but I add both as singletons...
program.cs

```
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISnackbar, SnackbarService>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<GrpcStatusInterceptor>();
```

May just be DI scope access to the Snackbar Service holding you up

*** Important Note: This is specific to my GRPC implementation ***

```
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<ProductsSvc.ProductsSvcClient>(options =>
        {
            options.Address = new Uri(builder.Configuration["prod_svc_base_url"]);
        })
            .AddInterceptor<GrpcStatusInterceptor>()
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => 
                new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));
```

Implementation...

```
using Grpc.Core;
using Grpc.Core.Interceptors;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using MudBlazor;

public class GrpcStatusInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    private readonly ISnackbar _snackBar;

    public GrpcStatusInterceptor(ISnackbar snackBar)
    {
        _snackBar = snackBar;
    }

    public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(
        TRequest request,
        ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
        AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        var call = continuation(request, context);

        return new AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse>(
            HandleResponse(call.ResponseAsync),
            call.ResponseHeadersAsync,
            call.GetStatus,
            call.GetTrailers,
            call.Dispose);
    }

    private async Task<TResponse> HandleResponse<TResponse>(Task<TResponse> inner)
    {
        try
        {
            return await inner;
        }
        catch (RpcException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.AlreadyExists ||
            ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.NotFound ||
            ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.FailedPrecondition ||
            ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.Unavailable)
        {
            return await inner; // Handle in App Components
        }
        catch (RpcException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.InvalidArgument || 
            ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.Aborted ||
            ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.Unimplemented ||
            ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.DataLoss ||
            ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.ResourceExhausted ||
            ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.Unknown ||
            ex.StatusCode == StatusCode.Internal)
        {
            _snackBar.Add(ex.Message, Severity.Error);

            dynamic responseVm = new 
            {
                Code = ex.StatusCode,
                Message = ex.Message
            };

            return MapResponse<TResponse>(responseVm);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Custom error", ex);
        }
    }

    private TResponse MapResponse<TResponse>(dynamic responseViewModel)
    {
        var concreteResponse = Activator.CreateInstance<TResponse>();

        concreteResponse?.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(responseViewModel.Code))?.SetValue(concreteResponse, responseViewModel.Code);

        concreteResponse?.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(responseViewModel.Message))?.SetValue(concreteResponse, responseViewModel.Message);

        return concreteResponse;
    }

}
```

Comment: This solved a similar issue for me.

Comment: Can you please show the full working example

Comment: My implementation is used for a GRPC interceptor, so it would not be specific to http error handling.  The answer (more of a hint) was to point out that access scope may have been the holdup...(see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences)