# DogStatsdService with dependency injection in ASPNETCore

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, datadog

I have tried to use DogStatsdService as a singleton object, but it seems that you need to call Flush so metrics are sent.

I have tried to register DogStatsdService as a scoped dependency, and it seems to work fine and custom metrics are sent in each request, however... is this the right way of using that service?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to understand how the service behaves in your program and choose an appropriate lifetime for it.

> **Singleton** which creates a single instance throughout the application.
> It creates the instance for the first time and reuses the same object
> in the all calls.
>
> **Scoped** lifetime services are created once per request within the
> scope. It is equivalent to a singleton in the current scope. For
> example, in MVC it creates one instance for each HTTP request, but it
> uses the same instance in the other calls within the same web request.
>
> **Transient** lifetime services are created each time they are requested.
> This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services.

This example from [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage) shows the difference.

For more details, you can refer to [akardon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38139500/18789859) for a better understanding of the three main lifecycles of dependency injection in .net core.