# cannot consume a scoped service from singleton

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, singleton, scoped

I am getting the above error and I realize why, but the odd behavior I see that it only happens in our Dev environment and not in for example our staging or Production environment and it is the exact same code.
In the startup there is :

```
services.AddSingleton<ExcahngeService>();
services.AddScoped<ITradingService, TradingService>();
```

This throws the error:
"cannot consume a scoped service from singleton"

Could this  be due to a timing issue, where the environment is slower ?

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences) and learn more about the lifetime of scoped and singleton.

Comment: The reason you are only seeing this error in your developer environment, is because Microsoft decided (probably because of performance concerns) to only check for these types of issues while the application is running in dev mode. For more info, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scope-validation).

Comment: Thanks @Steven 
We will need to correct our code nevertheless to allow us to have a working solution in Development.

Comment: Even if you see the error in the development environment, the error exists, because injecting scoped instances in singletons is most likely a bug. Even if you don't see the exception in production, your program is most likely broken anyway. It's very important to fix the issue.

Comment: @Steven this section might be more relevant as it specifically says "By default, in the development environment, resolving a service from another service with a longer lifetime throws an exception" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scoped instance` lifetime is limited, It is only available per request. So you are consuming an instance from Scoped service into Singleton and the error throws because of the scoped service is disposed. Either make both `Singleton` or `Scoped`

Answer (score 0):

As Microsoft best practice you should create new scope and get scoped service from ServiceProvider
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service