# How to have a global variable which stores objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a class that is my fake repository, I created a global variable `list<Ticket>`, when I add some objects to the `AddNewTicket()` function, I want it to be added to `addedTickets`  variable, and again when the `AddNewTicket()` function called, I want the previous values remain, and the new ticket would add at the end of the list.
here is what I have tried, but the list would get empty for each request.

```
public class TicketRepository : ITicketRepository
{
    private readonly FakeDbContext _context;
    List<Ticket> addedTickets = new List<Ticket>();

    public TicketRepository()
    {
        _context = new FakeDbContext();
    }

    public bool AddNewTicket(Ticket ticket)
    {
        _context.Tickets.Add(ticket);
        addedTickets.Add(ticket);
        return true;
    }

 }
```

my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITicketService, TicketService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITicketRepository, TicketRepository>();
```

%%%%%%%%%%
**I want something like in-memory Database.**
%%%%%%%%%%

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences

Comment: @Steve I have changed all to AddScoped<>, still doesn't work.

Comment: Singleton, always the same for every request. Did you read the accepted answer there?