# Trying to Understand the "behind-the-scenes" of ASP.NET Core... Scoped, Singleton, etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor-server-side

So I am currently using C# ASP.NET Core to develop web applications.
I am specifically using Blazor however I am just trying to get a full understanding of the behind-the-scenes of ASP.NET Core.

Inside the **Program.cs** we can call methods such as `AddScoped`, `AddTransient`, and `AddSingleston`.
From what understanding, it seems like if I have a class inside this project it will automatically call the constructor trying to pass in all of these classes, correct?
For example, if I do "`AddScoped<ClassName>`" it will look at my brand new class's constructor and try to pass in `Constructor(ClassName cn)`

Will it attempt to do that for each and every object in Scoped, Transient and Singleton, etc?
Should I only make my constructor of my classes accept only the classes I'd like to inject in or do I need to have my constructor inject them all in whether I use them or not?

Thanks!

I've tried to add a few Scoped, and Singletons into the Program.cs class and it seems like the behind-the-scenes magic is only injecting whatever the constructor can accept, whether that is all the classes or just one/few.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AddTransient, AddScoped and AddSingleton Services Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences)

Comment: Dependency Injection (DI) is commonly used in software architecture. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection Defining lifetimes will determine when instances are created and how long they stick around. (Lifetime) The link posted by @PeterB explains the lifetimes, but understanding how, and why DI is used is really important.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, I understand that it's DI and I understand the differences in when the object will be disposed depending if it is Transient, Scoped, or Singleton, however my main question is how it invokes the constructor behind-the-scenes.
Can I mix/match any classes in my constructors and it will place it only the ones that the constructor is asking for, or should I always have the same signature for every constructor?

Comment: Your question seems unclear. It would hardly be useful, even impossible, to write an app where every constructor has the same parameters. You write your class constructor with whatever parameters it requires to do its job. When the DI container tries to instantiate it, it looks at the ctor's parameters and instantiates every one. If you forgot to configure any parameter by using `AddTransient` etc. beforehand, it throws an error.