# Are Scoped or Singleton services lost on page refresh (In Blazor Web Assembly)

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I want to know if In Blazor web assembly what happens to scoped and singleton services when the page refreshes without openning a new tab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AddTransient, AddScoped and AddSingleton Services Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire app is unloaded and reloaded on an actual refresh, so all services are unloaded as well.