# How to use dependency injection for helper classes after an API call returns in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, dependency-injection

I'm writing a .NET API that accepts a request, saves the request to a database, then runs further validation/processing.  Since the validation takes a long period of time, we're saving the request to the database and returning an API response before validating the data.  Validation occurs asynchronously, ultimately sending the requester an email with the validation results.

Here's my problem: I inject the helper class in my controller class.  After the API returns, I can no longer access my DB Context, ultimately killing attempts to fetch/retrieve data during the validation process.

Here are snippets of my *trimmed* code:

**PostExlController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ExlPolicyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly PolicyBR _policyRules;

    public ExlPolicyController(PolicyBR policyRules)
    {
        _policyRules = policyRules;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<object>> PostExlPolicy([FromBody] Domain.Domain.ProgramBusiness programBusinessRequest)
    {
        // ...access arg level...

        // ...generate TrackingId...

        // Save each <PolicyRequests> from the JSON to the database
        int policyRequestsProcessed;
        policyRequestsProcessed = await _policyRules.SavePolicies(trackingId, programBusinessRequests);

        // Process the policy requests (including data-massaging and validation) and return our response
        _policyRules.ValidatePolicies(trackingId);
        return Ok(...);
    }
}
```

**PolicyBR.cs**

```
public class PolicyBR
{
    private readonly ProgramBusinessContext _programBusinessContext;

    public PolicyBR(ProgramBusinessContext programBusinessContext)
    {
        _programBusinessContext = programBusinessContext;
    }

    public async Task<int> SavePolicies(string trackingId, List<ProgramBusinessRequest> programBusinessRequest)
    {
        // Transform the request's policies into their <PolicyRequests> table 
        List<PolicyRequests> policies = programBusinessRequest.Select(programBusinessRequest => new PolicyRequests
        {
            ...new req...
        }).ToList();

        // Save the policies to the <PolicyRequests> table
        _programBusinessContext.PolicyRequests.AddRange(policies);
        await _programBusinessContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Create a record of the request in our <PBHistoryLog> table
        PBHistoryLog pbHistoryLog = new PBHistoryLog
        {
            ...log...
        };
        
        // Save the overall request to the <PBHistoryLog> table
        _programBusinessContext.PBHistoryLogs.Add(pbHistoryLog);
        await _programBusinessContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Return the number of saved policies
        return policies.Count;
    }

    public ProgramBusinessRequest MassageRequestWithDefaults(ProgramBusinessRequest programBusinessRequest)
    {
        // Validation code here...

        return programBusinessRequest;
    }

    public async Task ValidatePolicies(string trackingId)
    {
        // Fetch the requests from the <PolicyRequests> table, filtered for 
        // <trackingId> and a <RequestStatus> of "Pending"

        var policyRequests = _programBusinessContext.PolicyRequests
            .Where(pr => pr.TrackingId == trackingId)
            .Where(pr => pr.RequestStatus == RequestStatus.Pending.ToString())
            .ToList();

        // Initialize markers for success
        int totalRecords = policyRequests.Count;
        int successfulRecords = 0;
        int failedRecords = 0;

        // Massage and validate each policy request
        foreach (var policyRequest in policyRequests)
        {
            // Massage JsonRequest
            var massagedRequest = MassageRequestWithDefaults(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProgramBusinessRequest>(policyRequest.Jsonrequest));

            // Validate massaged JsonRequest
            var requestValidator = new ProgramBusinessRequestValidator(massagedRequest);
            List<ValidationErrorMessage> errors = requestValidator.ValidateProgramBusinessRequest();

            //...determine error count...

            // Update the <PolicyRequests> table with the validation results
            _programBusinessContext.PolicyRequests.Update(policyRequest);
            await _programBusinessContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Update the <PBHistoryLog> table with the request results
            var historyLog = _programBusinessContext.PBHistoryLogs
                .Where(pbHl => pbHl.TrackingId == trackingId)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            historyLog.ProcessEndDate = DateTime.Now;
            historyLog.SuccessfulCount = successfulRecords;
            historyLog.FailedCount = failedRecords;

            // Save the overall request to the <PBHistoryLog> table
            _programBusinessContext.PBHistoryLogs.Update(historyLog);
            await _programBusinessContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        // Send our email summary
        SendEmailSummary(trackingId);
    }

    public void SendEmailSummary(string trackingId)
    {
        // Fetch the validation counts and timestamps from the <PBHistoryLog> table
        var historyLog = _programBusinessContext.PBHistoryLogs
                .Where(pbHl => pbHl.TrackingId == trackingId)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        //...variables...

        // Fetch the requests from the <PolicyRequests> table, filtered for <trackingId>
        var policyRequests = _programBusinessContext.PolicyRequests
            .Where(pr => pr.TrackingId == trackingId)
            .ToList();

        // Define mailer
        // Write HTML email
        // Send email
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
...
builder.Services.AddScoped<PolicyBR>();
...
```

I've tried instantiating new contexts within **PolicyBR.cs** (ignoring the dependency injection), which allowed the command to run successfully.  However, that doesn't feel like clean code.  Is this okay, or is there another pattern I should be employing here?

Comment: Is your context injected as scoped?

Comment: If you're doing background processing, this is ultimately something you want to do in a more durable fashion, for instance by making use of durable messages or a tool like Hangfire. Either way, the part that you run in parallel in the background should be wrapped in its own DI scope. This can be done manually (using a decorator for instance) or the infrastructure of tools like Hangfire can wrap the operation in a scope for you.

Comment: What's the dependency lifetime? You can read this: "[AddTransient, AddScoped and AddSingleton Services Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38138100/7099900)"

Comment: PolicyBR is injected as Scoped in Program.cs.  I thought that a singleton may help, but I'm unsure if that's a wise route for this task considering how many times the API will be called and the helper/logic class will be used.

Comment: As long as you inject your DBContext directly you can't go singleton here. That one shouldn't be shared. If you register your DBContext via a Factory then you could inject the factory and retrieve an actual DBContext then from that safely. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/